# Push notification for holiday calendar

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I've implemented this snippet to create a watch event for passed calendar:

```
try
{
  $channel = new \Google_Service_Calendar_Channel;
  $channel->setId($id);
  $channel->setType('web_hook');
  $channel->setAddress($notification_url);
  $channel->setParams(['ttl' => $ttl]);
  $channel = $this->client->events->watch($calendar->getId(), $channel);
}
catch(\Google_Service_Exception $e)
{
  var_dump($e->getErrors());
}
```

This works well with all calendars (also shared calendars) except holiday and contacts calendar. With those the event watch endpoint response is `400 - Push notifications are not supported by this resource (reason pushNotSupportedForRequestedResource)`.

User gives to my application grants for calendars, calendars.readonly, email and profile.

Anyone known why of this behavior only with those calendars?

Answer (score 0):

Well, make sure that you can see this holiday in the calendar that you are getting.

You can verify it in your own calendar by checking the other calendar that are enable in your calendar.

Here is the screenshot that shows the Holiday calendar is enabled in my calendar. [image]

Comment: Yes i can see `Holidays in Italy` calendar. Using the Calendar Id i retrieve the calendar correctly